# How to check if an element contains another element in jQuery

Tags: jquery, validation, contains, xval, jquery-validate

I am using xVal combind with the jquery.validate plugin, but have come across a slight problem in that it is posting validation messages twice in a certain instance. I think this bug should be fairly easily fixed with some clever jQuery in the placement of the error message.

I am trying to find a way to see if a ul already contains an li with some text in it.

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
     $("ul.errors:not(:contains(" + error + "))").append(error);
}
```

I thought something like the above may work, but not such luck. error.toString() does not work either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Give a look to the [:has](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/has) selector:

```
$("ul:has(li:contains('" + error + "'))")
```

The above selector will select the `UL` elements which have a `LI` element that contains the `error` text.

Answer (score 0):

Not having that plugin here, I can't tell what the appropriate property is to get the error text, but you can use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) to do a `console.log` of `error` and see what it is.

You'll also need to put quotes around the string.

```
$("ul.errors:not(:contains('" + errorString + "'))")
```

...and don't forget to escape for any single quotes in the error message!

Comment: yeah, i just realised and changed the answer now. :)

Answer (score 0):

What is `error` in your code?
First you refer to it as a string `:contains(" + error + ")`, but then you refer to it as an element - `.append(error);`.
If this is an element, try getting its text by using `$(error).text()`, and search for the text in the ul.